# code for integers 1 to 100 in a JComboBox, not adding them one by one

Tags: java, jcombobox

I'm new in programming and trying to understand the basics. im trying to compute two integers from a JComboBox and have the result in a JTextField when the JButton is clicked. but how do i set the numbers 1 to 100 by not typing them 1,2,3,4,..30,31..and so forth. i just got the code for JButton and it works with this code

```
// I used this to call the numbers into the JComboBox
// but it would be a nightmare if i will continue to do this until 100  

cb1.addItem(new Integer(1));
cb1.addItem(new Integer(2));
cb1.addItem(new Integer(3));
// ...

cb2.addItem(new Integer(1));
cb2.addItem(new Integer(2));
cb2.addItem(new Integer(3));
// ...

// the code for the JButton which i got from this site

int cb1Int = Integer.parseInt(cb1.getSelectedItem().toString());
int cb2Int = Integer.parseInt(cb2.getSelectedItem().toString());
txt.setText(String.valueOf(cb1Int + cb2Int));
```

This codes worked perfectly fine but I think a shorter code
for calling the numbers 1 to 100 is a much help.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a for loop to add all the numbers to your combo box:

for example,

```
int numbers_to_add_max = 100;
for (int i = 1; i <= numbers_to_add_max; i++) {
    cb1.addItem(new Integer(i));
    cb2.addItem(new Integer(i));
}
```

Comment: ERROR
numbers_to_add_max is already defined in actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)
    int numbers_to_add_max = 100;

Comment: i just deleted the _to_add_max and it worked fine however the other JCOmboBox is just till 50. i tried to copy it and changed 100 to 50 but didn't work :(

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, but this is relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<=100;i++) 
{
cb1.addItem(new Integer(i));
cb2.addItem(new Integer(i));
}
```